# Google sheet conditional formating

Tags: conditional-statements, formatting

I have a 'Max Level' column and different 'Stocks' columns. I need to apply conditional formatting in Google Sheets based on the corresponding max level percentage compared to other stock columns. If stocks are below 30%, then the color would be red; likewise, for 30%-50%, green; 50%-70%, pink; 70%-100%, and greater than 100%.

image of the google sheet

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9jkL.jpg)

I tried to search the web, but I couldn't find the answer.